# Why does the adjective typisch in "eine typisch deutsche Aussprache" not have declension?

Tags: declension

Shouldn't we say “eine typische deutsche Aussprache” in this case?

Comment: Short answer: Because it is not an adjective.

Comment: Well, it is, but it's part of the phrase 'typisch deutsch'. And, with adjectival phrases, you only add endings to the last word. C. f. 'der gut gebildete Satz', 'ein die Bühne tretender Schauspieler', but not 'die lange, enge Straße'.

Comment: _Typisch_ ist in diesem Fall ein Adverb, das das Adjektiv _deutsche_ näher bestimmt. Adverbien werden nicht dekliniert.